# Set target folder in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I'm trying to symlink some files from `/path/to/folder1` to `/path/to/folder2` with some custom text appended to the resulting symlinks' names, however, after finally figuring out the correct handling of basename, the syntax either doesn't work or if I `cd` to `/path/to/folder2` and only use `${file%%.*}-something.txt` the files get symlinked to `/path/to/folder1`.

Here is my code:

```
for file in $(find /path/to/folder1 -iname '*.txt' ! -name 'file.txt' -type f)
do ln -s $file /path/to/folder2/${file%%.*}-something.txt
done
```

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for file `/path/to/folder1/abc.txt`, `${file%%.*}` will give you `/path/to/folder1/abc`

so you `ln` command translates to:

```
ln -s /path/to/folder1/abc.txt /path/to/folder2//path/to/folder1/abc-something.txt
```

if you want to link `/path/to/folder1/abc.txt` to `/path/to/folder2/abc-something.txt`, you can do it this way:

```
for file in $(find /path/to/folder1 -iname '*.txt' ! -name 'file.txt' -type f)
    do ln -s $file /path/to/folder2/$(basename $file .txt)-something.txt
done
```